# How to sort XDocument elements by attribute numerically?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

So I'm doing a simple sort on a list

```
<POSTBACK id="0"></POSTBACK>
```

```
   XDocument input = XDocument.Load( Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.xml"));
        XDocument data =
            new XDocument(
                new XElement("POSTBACK",
                    from node in input.Root.Elements()
                    orderby node.Attribute("id").Value ascending
                    select node));
```

But of course this sorts alphabetically so that something like this happens 89,9,90 etc.

How do I specify numerical comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoa. Heh. Didn't realize it was so simple...

```
 XDocument input = XDocument.Load( Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.xml"));
    XDocument data =
        new XDocument(
            new XElement("POSTBACK",
                from node in input.Root.Elements()
                orderby Convert.ToInt32( node.Attribute("id").Value)  ascending
                select node));
```